# When I edit a table in Google Sheet, it auto-changes my data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

When I put '4.8.8' into a cell in Google Sheets, it automatically converts it to '4.8.2008'. How do I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try clicking on format options on the tool bar. Check the image the below where I have it highlighted. Highlight your cells,columsn,rows,etc. and make sure the format is set to number or automatic. Use the format you need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- ### you can always force it by adding **`'`** in front of it like: **`'4.8.8`**

  [image]